# Cypress CY7C68014A FX2LP Port B and Port D data transfer speed

Tags: controller, usb, port

I want to use this fx2lp CY7C68014A as a slave device for high speed data exchange at the rate more than 120mbps.

I want to know that at what rate the data is transferred on the Port B and port D of this IC when 48MHz crystal oscillator is provided.. I want to connect other peripherals on port B and D depending on the rate of data transfer.

Can any one help with this query..

Thanks,

Dhara

Comment: 48MHz should give you 48 Mbps since I do not see DDR support on the PORT B and PORT D.

Comment: What if I fetch the data from Endpoints..?? Will it give me data rate above 100mbps..??

Comment: If you are using USB to fetch data, it should give you 480 Mbps for High speed. Posted the details in answer.

Comment: if you want to use MCU GPIO then without DMA you can forget about real speed. To ensure full USB speed you need to use FIFO interface instead but if you need custom IO handling you're out of luck. In such case the best option would be to use FX3 as it contains programmable interface but even that is really constrained and not suitable for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The USB peripheral controller has internal PLL which can multiply the input frequency and provide the speed for HS and FS speed as per the specification.

HS - High Speed - 480Mbps
FS - Full Speed - 12 Mbps

The internal PLL can have x20 multiplier.
It depends on your firmware handling the data transfer whether it can use the bandwidth properly.

So in conclusion, it can provide till 480 Mbps for High Speed devices and 12 Mbps for full speed devices.

Thanks